# changing date format with only months and year

Tags: r, date, format

I have a column with dates that are formatted like this:

```
yyyymm (e.g. 201809)
```

I want them to be formatted like this:

```
mm.yyyy (e.g. 09.2018)
```

I tried:

```
FF5factors$date <- strptime(FF5factors$date, format= "%Y%m")
format(FF5factors$date, format="%m.%Y")
```

But it only returns `NA` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some alternatives.  The question did not provide date in reproducible form so we assume the first line below although the first 4 alternatives will also work with `date <- "201809"` and with `date <- factor(201809)` .

```
date <- 201809

# 1
sub("(....)(..)", "\\2.\\1", date)
## [1] "09.2018"

# 2
library(zoo)
format(as.yearmon(format(date), "%Y%m"), "%m.%Y")
## [1] "09.2018"

# 3
paste(substr(date, 5, 6), substr(date, 1, 4), sep = ".")
## [1] "09.2018"

# 4
format(as.Date(paste0(date, "01"), "%Y%m%d"), "%m.%Y")
## [1] "09.2018"

# 5
sprintf("%02d.%d", date %% 100, date %/%100)
## [1] "09.2018"
```

Comment: library(zoo)
format(as.yearmon(format(date), "%Y%m"), "%m.%Y") worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
d <- '201809'
format(as.Date(d,'%Y%M'),'%m.%Y')
[1] "09.2018"
```

Comment: Gives me the following error message: Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Quite strange, to me it works fine. You can try to use `as.Date.character()` instead of `as.Date()`.

Comment: @s_t Your codes are working. But at the end, the output is not in Date format. Your result is giving output in character format. So it is not so different  using paste function like `d<-"201809"; paste(substr(d,5,6),substr(d,1,4),sep=".")`

Comment: @maydin you are completely right (and thanks to validate my code), but OP does not seem to be interested about it, he/she did not explicit the class of the output. All the solutions by @G. Grothendieck have as result `"character"` and, due the fact that OP choose the complete answer of G. Grothendieck (that I give +1), it means it's not definitely interested about it.

Comment: @s_t  You are right. I especially focused on the format when  I was trying to solve it on my computer. So in that sense, actually your quick answer is not different than the approved one.

Comment: @maydin TBH I suspect that if there are not at least day, month and year, it is not considered by R as date, or formatting it with `format()`, but maybe I'm wrong.